# django HttpResponseRedirect from function

Tags: django

I have a code like this

```
def checkLogin(request)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return None
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(login))

def somePage(request)
    checkLogin(request)  #kicks the user out if not login

    #do other things here if not kick out
```

I want to checkLogin in  many of my views, so I want to put it in a function to be used easily.

However the HttpResponseRedirect is not working for some reasons. I can use render but not httpresponseredirect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your use case you can use the login_required decorator https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

In general though, only the return value of the view function gets returned as a HttpResponse you could do something like:

```
def checkLogin(request)
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return None
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(login))

def somePage(request)
    needs_login = checkLogin(request)  #kicks the user out if not login
    if needs_login:
        return needs_login

    #do other things here if not kick out
```

The only exception to this is when you want to return a 404. you can raise a 404 exception which will bubble through to the view.

```
def checkLogin(request)
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        raise Http404

def somePage(request)
    checkLogin(request)  #kicks the user out if not login

    #do other things here if not kick out
```

Answer (score 3):

There is built-in Django solution `from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required` you need just put decorator above:

```
@login_required
def somFunc():
```

or if it is generic view not function `from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator`:

```
@method_decorator(login_required)
def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
```